# Using PHP shell_exec to print PDF on the network automatically to a network printer not working

Tags: php, pdf, wamp, tcpdf, shell-exec

I'm using shell_exec() to print a PDF that is stored on a LAN automatically to a printer on the LAN through Adobe Reader using the following PHP code (all on one line):

```
shell_exec("'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe' 
/t \\hnurensp01\RepairTickets\179694.pdf \\hnurenfp01\Accounts_FS-1128MFP");
```

What I expect this to do is open adobe reader, open the PDF on the network and print to the network printer. When running the PHP script with this line, it doesn't open adobe reader or print it. However, when I copy that code and execute in a command prompt (client-side), it works and prints. There is only slight modifications to the command line (all on one line):

```
"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
/t \\hnurensp01\RepairTickets\179694.pdf \\hnurenfp01\Accounts_FS-1128MFP
```

Is it to do with the PHP script executing on the server-side? I've tried running the same command line on the server and it works too. It just seems to be when it's going through PHP, it does nothing.

My end result must be printing out a server-side PDF with as little interaction from the end-user as possible. Note: this is a WAMP environment.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Tried put the code into a batch file and calling it that way, still didn't work. Tried using `exec()` and `shell_exec()` but still no joy. For some reason when I run the batch file by double-clicking it, it works fine. It's when I call it using PHP, it doesn't do anything except open two instances of acrord32.exe that doesn't close and therefore the PHP script seems to never complete. I'm soo confused...

Comment: Try escaping the slashes in AcrdoRD2's path too. `C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\...`

Comment: Tried that but still no joy. Also, I tried escaping the paths for the PDF and the printer - still nothing. :(

Comment: Ok, `echo shell_exec("'C:\\Program Files...")` and see what it prints. Possibly helpful error messages.

Comment: Also, tried different switches for Adobe Reader so no switch to just open it - nothing happens, and /p to open with print dialog - nothing happens. When I say nothing happens, I actually mean two instances of acrord32.exe start for a few seconds and then close. So, it would seem it's not the PDF file that's the problem, more acrord32.exe :|

Comment: Printed nothing, I tried print_r(shell_exec(....)) and it returned 1

Comment: Just to be sure, please check if your PHP is running in safe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10798/discussion-between-weedave-and-nadh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe' /t \\hnurensp01\RepairTickets\179694.pdf \\hnurenfp01\Accounts_FS-1128MFP"
```

It returns:

```
'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe' /t \hnurensp01\RepairTickets9694.pdf \hnurenfp01\Accounts_FS-1128MFP
```

In PHP, the backslash serves as a 'special' character, since it's used to produce tabs and newlines `\t` and `\n`. The proper way to escape a backslash, is by prepending another one: `\\` produces `\` as output.

This is why your PHP script doesn't work. The double backslashes will be printed to the shell as if you only typed one! You will need to escape *every* backslash in that line of code:

```
shell_exec("'C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe' 
    /t \\\\hnurensp01\\RepairTickets\\179694.pdf \\\\hnurenfp01\\Accounts_FS-1128MFP");
```

Comment: Couldn't get it working using Adobe Reader. Tried LPR commands with LPD service etc - disastrous for me! lol. Ended up using Fox It PDF Reader with a similar command: `START "Print Document" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe" /t "D:\xampp\htdocs\instrument\app\webroot\Docs\%1.pdf" "\\<machine_name>\<printer_name>"`

Comment: I am executing echo shell_exec("'C:\\Program Files\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\\Foxit Reader.exe' 
    /t \\\\c:\\billdoc_260.pdf \\\\192.168.0.122\\EPSON TM-T82II Receipt52"); where 192,168,0,122 is Ipaddess and EPSON TM-T82II Receipt52 is printer name but not printing the file neither giving any error. Where i am wrong?